# Array extension called from other module

Tags: swift

Array extension methods are unavailable from other modules (for example the XCTest project)

For the sake of simplicity the code below does nothing but it can be used to reproduce the error

```
import Foundation

extension Array {
    mutating func myMethod(toIndex: Int) -> Int! {
        // no real code, it's here only to show the problem
        return 0
    }
}
```

Calling it from the same module works as expected but from a test class don't

```
class MyProjectTests: XCTestCase {
    func testMoveObjectsFromIndexes1() {
        var arr = ["000", "001", "002", "003"]
        arr.myMethod(0)
    }
}
```

I think this is correct because the method visibility is restricted to its own module, indeed I obtain the error `'[String]' does not have a member named 'myMethod'`

I've tried to define the extended method as `public` as shown below

```
extension Array {
    public mutating func myMethod(toIndex: Int) -> Int! {
        // no real code, it's here only to show the problem
        return 0
    }
}
```

But I get the compile error `'Extension of generic type 'Array<T>' from a different module cannot provide public declarations'`

Until Beta 7 using `public` solved the problem but under XCode 6.1 (6A1046a) I obtain this error

How can I fix it to run under other modules/projects?

Comment: Why extend Array when you could declare a public top-level function?

Comment: You can't fix this problem.  Swift 1.1 disabled public extensions of generic types outside your own module explicitly because the implementation was not the best when they did allow it.  Radar for its return.

Comment: @mattt this is just an example to reproduce the problem, the real code uses array items so it's perfect as extension

Comment: @CodaFi I've filed dozen of bugs about swift and this is the next, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Swift does not allow public extensions currently so you will need to include that extension swift file in your project and put it part of the target.

Answer (score 1):

While not entirely solving the original question, I did find that I could **test extension methods** in Swift 2.0 (Under XCode 7.0) by importing the module with the `@testable` directive:

`@testable import MyGreatModule`

Comment: Totally missed this new feature in Swift 2... thanks! This has solved many testing woes of fellow Swift-ers :)