# Override the `description` computed property of the `Optional` class

Tags: swift

I'd like to shorten up the syntax used for printing an optional, strictly for debugging purposes.

Right now:

```
var title:String? = "foo"
println("My title: \(title)") // My Title: Optional("foo")
```

I'd like to change it to something more concise, like this:

```
var title:String? = "foo"
println("My title: \(title)") // My Title: ?"foo"
```

Not sure how to override the description method though. Tried doing an extension on the Optional class and got stuck.

```
// Has no effect:
extension Optional {
  var description: String {
    return "foo"
  }
}
```

Comment: `Optional` doesn't conform to `Printable`, it conforms to `DebugPrintable`. However, trying to override `debugDescription` results in the error: 'extension of generic type 'Optional<T>' from a different module cannot provide public declarations'... (related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387262/array-extension-called-from-other-module)

Comment: It's ok, I don't need a public extension. Forgot there are two different protocols!